# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) even with a data validator - Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm working with Jikan API.
Here I have a `FutureBuilder` that display some data :

```
FutureBuilder<am.AnimeModel>(
                        future: getAnimeById(widget.malId),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            var data = snapshot.data!.data!; // <--- HERE ERROR
                            print(data.malId);

                            return AnimeDataCardWidget(
                              malId: data.malId,
                              pic: data.images!.jpg!.largeImageUrl,
                              title: data.title,
                              totalEpisode: data.episodes,
                              studios: data.studios![0].name != null
                                  ? data.studios![0].name
                                  : '--',
                              originalManga: data.source,
                              frenchVersion: data.titles,
                              creationDate: data.airing,
                              futureData: getFavAnimesId(),
                              score: data.score,
                            );
                          } else {
                            return const Center(
                              child: CustomLoadingAnimation(),
                            );
                          }
                        }),
```

When the user tap on listTile, the app opens a detailed page, and this page displays a card (see code above). It works really fine but not with animes that don't have the **'studio'** data.

As you can see, I check `if (snapshot.hasData)` but after that, it keep tells me that `data` is null.

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to fix this error, I change the line :

```
studios: data.studios![0].name != null
                                  ? data.studios![0].name
                                  : '--',
```

to this :

```
studios: data.studios?.isNotEmpty == true
                                      ? data.studios![0].name ?? '--'
                                      : '--',
```